# Sequelize include return single record instead all

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Using sequelize with expressjs, strangely sequelize return single record instead more than one. There are many records are inserted in shipping_addresses table against a single user. I don't want to remove raw:true it's because that result belongs to graphql that's why using raw:true,

```
shipping_addresses.belongsTo(users, { as: "userId", foreignKey: "userId"});
users.hasMany(shipping_addresses, { as: "shipping_addresses", foreignKey: "userId"});


sequelize.users.findOne({
    where:{...},
    include: [model:shipping_addresses, as:'shipping_addresses'],
    raw:true,
    nest:true
}).
```

Here is result

```
{ 
    id:1, 
    username:johndeo
    shipping_addresses: {
        id:1
        line:abc street
    }
}
```

What I am expecting

```
{ 
    id:1, 
    username:johndeo
    shipping_addresses: [
        {
            id:1
            line:abc street
        },
        {
            id:2
            line:another street
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-get](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-get)

You don't need `raw: true` option. Instead, call `get({plain: true})`

Sample Code

```
async function test() {
    const row = await Users.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'username'],
        where: { id: 1 },
        include: [{ model: ShippingAddresses, attributes: ['id', 'line'], as: 'shipping_addresses' }],
        nest: true
    });
    console.log(row.get({ plain: true }))
}

test()
```

Result

```
$ node test
{"pid":25056,"sql":"Executing (default): SELECT \"users\".\"id\", \"users\".\"username\", \"shipping_addresses\".\"id\" AS \"shipping_addresses.id\", \"shipping_addresses\".\"line\" AS \"shipping_addresses.line\" FROM \"users\" AS \"users\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"shipping_addresses\" AS \"shipping_addresses\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"shipping_addresses\".\"user_id\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 1;"}
{
  id: 1,
  username: 'johndeo',
  shipping_addresses: [ { id: 1, line: 'abc street' }, { id: 2, line: 'another street' } ]
}
```

Comment: anyways it's just used .dataValue instead

Answer (score 0):

try not using `raw: true` and `nest: true` for this case. I guess it should work

Comment: I don't want to remove raw:true it's because that result belongs to graphql that's why using raw:true.

Comment: then try remove `nest: true`

Comment: Please take look at my expected format.